# Heroku pipeline app returns 404: "no such app"

Tags: heroku, web-deployment, pipeline

I created three apps in Heroku and added them to a pipeline, but their URLs return a 404.

The apps are named like "app-name-dev", "app-name-stage", and "app-name". On the settings tab of each app, Heroku has given them auto-generated URLs, like "https://app-name-dev.herokuapp.com/", etc. But only the production URL works (the one not ending in -dev or -stage). The other 2 return 404 with the title "no such app".

Anyone know how to get Heroku pipeline apps to load in the browser? My code runs fine -- no errors -- because the production site loads fine. It's just -dev and -stage that won't load. Again, they're at default URLs assigned by Heroku -- no custom domains.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Duh, all I had to do was wait a few hours for some DNS entries to be updated somewhere. All 3 apps are loading now.